# Using operators select-able from a ComboBox

Tags: c#, combobox, calculator

Hey stackoverflow I have a question regarding selecting different math operators from a combobox for a calculator in visual studio. Whats the most simple and logical way to use casting for this? And how would I go about grabbing the selected operator from the combobox and using it as the mathematical operator for the problem?

Ive thrown together this winform to show you guys what I mean:
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eWu1X.png)

Comment: Keep track of the index of each item in the operator dropdown, then you can switch case on the selected index and do the operation.

Comment: `int.TryParse` for integers or `double.TryParse` for decimal numbers is a good way to convert a string to a number, because it tells you whether or not it was successful (and sets the out parameter to the converted value if it was).

Comment: So I get the 'TryParse' part but Im a bit lost on the indexing of each item, Im fairly new to c# so dont be to hard on me haha.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Lets consider following from the image you shared...

N1 = value of textbox1

N2 = value of textbox2

OP = selected value of combobox

On Button click, execute this.

STEPS

1. Convert/Parse N1 and N2 to number (either interger or double). You can use `int.TryParse` for integers or `double.TryParse` for decimals.
2. Convert combobox selecteditem to string and assign to OP. You can use `Convert.ToString()`. Check for `SelectedIndexChanged` event of `ComboBox` [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedindexchanged?view=netframework-4.7.2).
3. Write a Swich case for all the available operations.

   ```
   switch(OP)
   {
       case "+":
           N1 + N2;    
       break;

       ....
       ....
   }
   ```
4. Display result.

Comment: Im having trouble with step 2, how do I go about converting a combobox selecteditem to string and assigning it an alias.

Comment: Did you check the link I put with step 2?